# React - how to get async data from fetch POST

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm posting data from form to my json-server url localhost:3000/recipes and I'm trying to get data in other component without refreshing the page. I'm posting some data to recipes url and when i go back to other hashURL on page I need to refresh my page to get result. Is there any way to get data async from life cycles or something similar ?

```
componentDidMount() {
    recipesService.then(data => {
      this.setState({
        recipes: data
      });
    });
  }
```

recipe.service

```
const url = "http://localhost:3000/recipes";
let recipesService = fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json());
let sendRecipe = obj => {
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj)
  })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

module.exports = {
  recipesService,
  sendRecipe
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to use something like Redux. :)

Or you can create your cache for this component:

```
// cache.js
let value;
export default {
  set(v) { value = v; },
  restore() { return value; },
};

// Component.js
import cache from './cache';
...
async componentDidMount() {
  let recipes = cache.restore();
  if (!recipes) {
    recipes = await recipesService;
    cache.set(recipes);
  }
  this.setState({ recipes });
}
```

Comment: Redux is probably the right approach here or if it's just a child component you can pass it in as a prop.

Comment: Many thanks! I will teach how to implement redux in my app :)